# Why does expo gives error when install native-base

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

When I try to get native-base and when I run the app. It gives me that error. How can I fix that. I am using expo and I installed expo-font.

**PLEASE HELP!**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's a [bug](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3113) in the `native-base` package.

There is a [PR that resolves this issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/3123), but as of me writing this one - it's still not merged yet.

The only workaround is to either try to install older version of `native-base`, either fork the `native-base` package and apply in the `native-base` code [the change which fixes the issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/3123/commits/06637febf59ed398356875a16fcdaaddbc95a1df).

Or of course, wait... until `native-base` contributors accept the PR and release a new version with the fix.